# Getting value to show up using livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm using laravel and livewire and I'm trying to create an edit page. What I'm trying to do is get the value to show up in the textbox.
So for example my edit page has product info that I'm trying to edit, but my product name isn't displaying in the textbox.

Here is my code

My ProductEdit.php

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Products\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Product;
use Livewire\Component;

class ProductsEdit extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $product;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('products::livewire.edit-products', [
            'name' => $this->product->name
        ]);
    }

    public function updateProduct()
    {
        dd($this->name);
    }
}
```

My edit-products.blade.php

```
<div class="mt-1 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                    id="product_name"
                    type="text"
                    name="product_name"
                    value="{{ $product->name }}"
                    wire:model="name"
                >
</div>

<button wire:click="updateProduct" class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 text-green-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center">Save</button>
```

Comment: `updateProduct` to `updateName` as your looking for `wire:model="name"` changes

Comment: @KamleshPaul - sorry I forgot to add my save button which has the `updateProduct`

Comment: Your component views - the .blade file - needs to be a single root element. You now have two, a div and a button.

Comment: Also, the `updateProduct()` method can be fired manually through `wire:click`, but if your component ever gets a `$product` property, it will fire when that property is updated.

Comment: ok, but how do I get my product name to display in the textbox though?